# How to show ListView ind=side simpledialog

Tags: flutter

I am trying to show listview.builder inside simpledialog but it doesn't work
here is my code:

```
onTap: () {
    return showDialog(
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return SimpleDialog(
                 title: Text('names'),
                 children: [
                    ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: names.length,
                        itemBuilder: ((context, index) {
                            return SimpleDialogOption(
                                onPressed: () {
                                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                },
                                child: Text(names[index].name),
                            );
                    }))
                ],
            );
       },
       context: context);
   },
```

Comment: Is there any error displayed on the console? What the actual issue?

Comment: no thing showning in the screen

Comment: can you suggest any solution ??

Comment: for example if I print named[0].name it give me the name

Answer (score 0):

change this line:

```
names[index].name
```

to this:

```
names[index]name
```

It won't work if you use the period between the values. But you should get an error for that.